# The meaning of the title "A Sand County Almanac: And Sketches Here and There"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

["A Sand County Almanac: And Sketches Here and There"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Sand_County_Almanac) is the title of one of the earliest and most important books in environmental thought. [Source: Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZJVXpWrnxAc)

I know different meanings of the words in the title. But I don't get what exactly the title wants to say. More specifically, I'd like to know what meaning I should take words "Sand County" and "Almanac" to have. Any view would be welcomed and appreciated.

Comment: It's an almanac of a country which is sandy. There's not much more we can tell you than that; that string of words is not a well-recognized idiom or anything, so if it's got a deeper meaning, it must arise from th content of the work, and this site doesn't engage with content of specific works. If a literal "almanac of a country which is sandy" is unclear to you even after you've looked up each word in the dictionary, then please us why.

Comment: @DanBron - the word is County, without the R.  Sand County appears to be the author's fictionalized name, based on the real Sauk County in the U.S. State of Wisconsin.

Comment: @DanBron The author has a special style; he usually uses words with different meanings of them intended at the same time. This is one reason why it can be unclear after looking up words in dictionary. For example, "county" has two groups of different meanings, one is a region, province, or land, ..., and the other is noble, noble-born, classy, ... . It seems both groups are intended here. And, if not, which one in the first group of meanings is intended?

Comment: @Jooya As I said, interpretation of a *specific* author's works is off-topic here.

Comment: @DanBron What about the meaning of "Here and There" in the title? The for sure is not a matter of interpretation.

Comment: @Jooya That can be answered by a dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ***A Sand County Almanac: And Sketches Here and There*** is a 1949 non-fiction book by American ecologist, forester, and environmentalist Aldo Leopold. Describing the land around the author's home in **Sauk County**, Wisconsin, the collection of essays advocate Leopold's idea of a "land ethic", or a responsible relationship existing between people and the land they inhabit.

The [same Wikipedia article](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/A_Sand_County_Almanac) you yourself provided says the following:

> There is, in fact, no "Sand County" in Wisconsin. The term "sand counties" refers to a section of the state marked by sandy soils.

Comment: Good point. Thanks. The author has a special style; he usually uses words with different meanings of them intended at the same time. For example, "county" has two groups of different meanings, one is a region, province, or land, ..., and the other is noble, noble-born, classy, ... . It seems both groups are intended here. And, if not, which one in the first group of meanings is intended?

Comment: @Jooya Can't say. I'm not familiar with his works.

Comment: What about the meaning of "Here and There" in the title?

Comment: @Jooya It has nothing to do with the English language. Only readers familiar with his works can interpret those things more correctly. Possibly, he meant "in various places."

Comment: @Jooya Try reading the entire Wikipedia article. I'm sure you'll learn more from it.

Comment: county does not have two different meanings here at all. Here and there means throughout that county, which he names: Sand County. Here and there does have two meanings, though.